# Allocate Contiguous Memory and Assign to a Pointer

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, cython

I am trying to implement something in the `sklearn` codebase, where I have a function similar to this one:

```
cdef foo(double** bar_ptr): …
```

Which gets called like so

```
cdef double* bar_ptr = NULL
foo(&bar_ptr)
# … do something with bar_ptr
```

So, inside `foo` I need to somehow allocate memory and then return it via the pointer. I tried

```
cdef foo(double** bar_ptr):
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1, mode='c'] bar = np.zeros(3)
    bar_ptr[0] = <double *>bar.data
```

Which compiles but produces an error at runtime:

```
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1, mode='c'] bar = np.zeros(3)
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

Which I don't get because my bar array is 1 dimensional, or isn't it?

However, I am not convinced at all that this is the right approach. How does one go about this, preferably without resorting to `malloc` or similar?

Comment: It does look like it should work (I can't immediately see what's wrong). __However__ - the numpy array will not survive beyond the end of the function, so the memory you're returning will be invalid (unless you can find a way to store the numpy array somewhere outside the function).

Comment: @DavidW I see. So what would you recommend?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. Does it have to have that signature (to interface with some external C code?)? If so then you'll probably have to use malloc. If not then I'd just return the numpy array and get the pointer in the code that calls `foo`.